# Why is Facebook claiming that my facebook app 'is still calling Graph API v1.0' if I specified v2.2 version in koala?

Tags: facebook-graph-api, koala-gem

We have recently received two alerts regarding our facebook app.

> Your app is still calling Graph API v1.0 which will be
>   deprecated on April 30, 2015. You must upgrade this app to v2.0 or
>   greater before that date.
>
> To help you experience the potential effects of this migration,
>   starting tomorrow at 12pm PST, the admins, developers, testers and
>   Test Users associated with this app will be upgraded to use API v2.0
>   by default. This change won't affect your public users until April 30,
>   2015.
>
> You'll be able to temporarily opt-out of this behavior in the
>   Migrations tab of your app's dashboard - but the migration will be
>   automatically re-enabled every two weeks until April 30, 2015.
>
> For more information, please read our upgrade guide and login review
>   guide.

The second one is very similar and starts with:

> We have detected that your app is still calling Graph
>   API v1.0 which will be deprecated on April 30, 2015. You must upgrade
>   this app to v2.0 or greater before that date.

However, we have been using Graph API v2.2 for serveral months now by specifying api version in koala config (we always use koala to call GraphAPI):

```
 Koala.config.api_version = "v2.2"
```

Since we need the subscribed_apps endpoint, we are using v2.2. Switching to v1.0 results in `OAuthException, code: 12, message: (#12) Requires version v2.2 or higher [HTTP 400]` in case of subscribed_app calls.

I know that not specyfing a version at all results in choosing the oldest available one but we have specified the version in koala, so it's not the point in our case.

Is it possible to find out what caused the alert from Facebook?

Comment: Is your app id perhaps used in any additional context, for example using any social plugins such as the Like button etc., somewhere on some website?

Comment: Also, that warning is based on several days' calls and lags behind recent changes - if you've verified that your app is only using the current/new API versions you can ignore the warning

Comment: Thanks for your replies! Is it possible that making calls in Graph API Explorer caused this alert? I used a few access tokens for my pages granted to my app.

Comment: I too have this problem, and FB even sent a screenshot of the app failing while using 2.0, so perhaps there's a koala issue here after all.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I have found an answer to my problem and would like to present all the facts.

For older applications you will see a different message, for example that your app upgrade is completed in 98%.

For applications created quite recently (mine was created in July 2014) that are already version v2.0 or higher you might receive an alert but the message you can check at https://developers.facebook.com/apps/upgrade/ says:

> You do not need to upgrade any apps.

I also received a piece of advice from Facebook:

> If you're confident your app is upgraded, you can go into the
>   Migrations tab of the Settings section of the App Dashboard - and flip
>   the "Use Graph API v2.0 by default" switch to "On" - then you can be
>   sure you're API migration is ready for April 30th.
>
> If you don't see that setting then you're already using v2.0 or
>   greater, so you have nothing to worry about.

If you are sure that neither your server-side calls nor your client-side logins use version v1.0 or you chose option "Use Graph API v2.0 by default", you can assume that your app is ready for April 30th and ignore the alerts.

Here you can find some information about the bug that probably causes these alerts: https://developers.facebook.com/bugs/957020271005002/. This issue won't be fixed.